# Dropdown list in Jhipster entities using PrimeNg

Tags: jhipster, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I'm trying to use PrimeNg in dropdown list of Jhipster generated entities:

my .jdl file

```
`entity Testcns (testcns) {
  libCns String,
  dateCreaEnr Instant
}
entity Testfam (testfam) {
  nomFam String,
  dateCreaEnr Instant
}
relationship ManyToOne {                   
  Testfam{testcns(libCns)} to Testcns      
}              
`
```

UI create new Testfam
[image: UI create new Testfam]

What I want is a dropdown with filters instead:
[image: What i want]

the searching is not working in my code: 
[image: Searching dropdown]

and here is my code of the select:

```
my code with primeng
          <h3>Content with Filters</h3>
        <p-dropdown name="customizedselect" [options]="testcns" [(ngModel)]="testfam.testcns"
                    filter="filter" [autoWidth]="false" [style]="{'width':'150px'}">
            <ng-template let-testcns pTemplate="item">
                <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="'display': 'inline-block'">
                    <span >{{testcns.libCns}}</span>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </p-dropdown>
```

Any tips? Thank you very much

Comment: i have successfully installed primeng from https://github.com/sudheerj/generator-jhipster-primeng

Comment: but I dont't know how to implement primeng in a existing entity generated by jhipster